# How to write a main python script to integrate multiple py files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Initially I have executed like this...

pyinstaller - - onefile a.py b. py c. py

What I want to do is to write one main script file eg: main.py by which I execute like this..

pyinstaller - - onefile main.py

The main script file must include all the py files that are listed above..

Help me to solve. TIA

Comment: Wouldn't basics imports do it?

Comment: After import how will the files executed. Could you please share some sample code

Answer (score 0):

main.py:

```
import a
import b
import c
```

then just

```
> pyinstaller main.py
```

Comment: But a b c are not packages.. They are files

Comment: If they are in the same folder, you can import them.